# Is it possible to play Ori and the Blind Forest with only a keyboard?

Tags: ori-and-the-blind-forest

I downloaded this game and liked it at first, but later found that it apparently requires to tap keys silly to jump on walls, etc. Is it really possible to play this game with only a keyboard? While climbing walls, I'm drumming on the space bar, but Ori still climbs slowly or falls.

Do I have to use a game pad, or is it possible to play this game with only a keyboard?

Comment: I'm guessing you're tapping wrong. Or in other words: the moment you let the key go, you're already pressing it again with another finger, so to the game it looks like you're keeping the key down instead of tapping it.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I haven't finished the game yet, but 95% completed so far, so it is definitely possible with keyboard (azerty) only.

Most controls are fine, but Dash is difficult because with keyboard you get only 8 directions easily (and for diagonals you have to press 2 keys simultaneously, to get more precise angle you need to stop holding one of the key briefly, it is not simple).

I had hard time when the ginso tree was flooded, but then it became smooth again. Second really hard time was inside the volcano.

The main critic I have is that I often confuse keys x (fire) and c (dash) and ctrl (sprint) and shift (glide), because they are too close and I end up messing up a difficult run. I also use s (crash) scarcely because of the need to locate the s key under my fingers.

I am a casual gamer, it took me 25 hours and 1500 deaths to came to these 95%, so from what I seen in the walkthrough videos, it is smoother with pads, but certainly not impossible with keyboard only, I did it.

Comment: I finished in 32h and 2100 deaths for 100% complete. This weekend I played again, and finished it in 9h and 500 deaths, and I was also surprised to pass Kuro chase first try. I took more pleasure this time, so keyboard only is definitely possible and enjoyable, just need a bit of practice :-)

Comment: Finally after some more sessions, I stabilize around 3h30 and 80 deaths. They are some spots that are always uneasy (mainly these where you have to bash a ball at a precise direction) but it's globally ok. Also I use down arrow to crash things, and ctrl (sprint) more than what i saw on pad videos, it come naturally with keyboard. Hope you enjoy this game !

Answer (score 0):

I played with mouse and keyboard and had no problem with climbing a wall.
You get the climbing ability later on.

Then there this ability where you swap yourself with projectiles or enemies with right click of the mouse.

I think it will be much much harder to do so with a controller than with a mouse, especially when the action is intense.

Keep on playing, I don't think you will regret that.